# Unauthorized access exception when updating users in Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I'm creating a project that will update certain attributes of all people in an Active Directory server. When I go to commit changes, I get an unauthorized access exception even though I pass in credentials of a service account to log in as to do the changes. Note, ROOT is the top level directory entry where to start search, with a service account username and password passed into the constructor.

```
try
{
    DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(ROOT);
    ds.Filter = ("(&(objectCategory=Person)(employeeID=9999))");
    ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
    SearchResult result1 = ds.FindOne();
    DirectoryEntry person = result1.GetDirectoryEntry();

    //update AD fields
    person.Properties["title"].Value = "Some title";
    person.CommitChanges();
    ROOT.CommitChanges();
}
```

When `person.CommitChanges();` is run, the title attribute in Active Directory would be changed. It does so for some other users. But other times it appears as if the service account credentials aren't being used and "Access Denied" error is shown.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on an account that it couldn't update and verified that your service account does have permissions to update it?

Comment: The service account has full permissions read/write to all users in the group

Comment: Are there any Deny rules in the permissions? If you look up the account you are can't modify in AD Users and Computers, go to the Security tab and click Advanced, you ca use the "Effective Access" tab, select the service account and make sure it can update the `title` attribute.

Comment: I've never seen AD lie about that. If it says "access denied" it's because the account you're using doesn't have permissions to do what you're doing.

Comment: @GabrielLuci In 99% the tool will give you correct results, but there is always 1% where it will calculate them incorrectly. The documentation mentions it and we faced such situation while developing our own permissions tool. The only valid 100% check is to log in under the service account interactively and modify the attribute of the problematic user via aduc

Comment: @oldovets The "Effective Access" feature you mean? Yeah, I have seen that before... I think when there's weird overlapping inherited permissions if I remember correctly.